# Copy complete partition mapping

Tags: hard-drive, filevault, data-recovery

How do I copy the whole partition map for a drive 'cloned' with DD? Same size hard drive for input and output of DD. Device block size was 4096 Bytes on input disk, 512 Bytes on output disk. Filevault 2 partitions on source.

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't clone the partition map of a 4096 Byte disk to a 512 Byte disk (and vice versa) directly. 4096 Byte/512 Bytes are the device block sizes here.

The major differences are the 1st block (block=0) and the GPT header (block=1):

While the MBR (PMBR) on a 512 disk only occupies 512 bytes (Block(512)=0), the MBR on a 4096-disk occupies the whole first block and the GUID starts at block(4096)=1 (which would translate to block(512)=8).

The first GPT header on a 512 disk occupies the second block (Block(512)=1), the first GPT header on a 4096-disk occupies the whole second block and the GUID partition table starts at block(4096)=2 (which would translate to block(512)=16).

Examples:

Device block size: 512

```
                0           1         PMBR
                1           1         Pri GPT header
                2          32         Pri GPT table
               34           6         
               40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
           409640 size-main-v      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
totalsize-1269576     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     totalsize-40           7         
     totalsize-33          32         Sec GPT table
      totalsize-1           1         Sec GPT header
```

Device block size: 4096 (in parenthesis the "respective" 512 start block/block size)

```
               0 (0)           1     (8)        PMBR
               1 (8)           1     (8)        Pri GPT header
               2(16)           4    (32)        Pri GPT table
               6(48)       51200(409600)      1 GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
           76806(..) size-main-v              2 GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
totalsize-158697(..)      158692(..)          3 GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC       
     totalsize-5(..)           4    (32)        Sec GPT table
     totalsize-1(..)           1     (8)        Sec GPT header
```

---

As a consequence don't clone the partition table but create it yourself:

```
sudo gpt create diskX #(with diskX the disk identifier of the target disk(512)
```

Then add the EFI, the main partition and the Recovery HD. Just start at block 40(512) on your disk(512) while multiplying the sizes of the disk(4096) partitions by 8:

```
sudo gpt add -b 40 -s (size-old-efi*8) -i 1 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B diskX
sudo gpt add -b 40+(size-old-efi*8) -s (size-old-main-vol*8) -i 2 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC diskX
sudo gpt add -b 40+(size-old-efi*8)+(size-old-main-vol*8) -s 1269536 -i 3 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC diskX
```

Your source EFI partition probably has either 51200 blocks(4096) or 76800 blocks(4096).

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly to create the partitions which seem to match the originals. However, when I do a "diskutil cs list" I don't see the corestorage volume and I can't see any volumes through finder. Any idea why?

Comment: @MikeJ Is the source disk still installed?

Comment: No, it is not. It's an unokugged external drive.

Comment: @MikeJ EFI and Recovery HD usually aren't mounted. And a locked FV2 neither. The FV2 LV should be visible though in `diskutil cs list`! Do you remember the dd commands used? You may see them in your .bash_history

Comment: I'd tried dd'ing the whole disk: sudo dd if=/dev/disk6 of=/dev/disk3 bs=1m after which I applied the partition mapping. I could post gpt and my math. Does dd w/ filevault2 only work when dd'ing a partition vs whole disk?